# C# - Dictionary<key, value> to List<T>

Tags: c#, ilist, idictionary

I want to map my `Dictionary<int, string>` to a `List<Customer>` where `Customer` has two properties `Id` and `Name`. Now I want to map my integer `Key` of the dictionary to the `List<Customer>[i].Key` property and `Value` of the dictionary to `List<Customer>[i].Name` iteratively.

Need help for the same.

Comment: How is your dictionary declared?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>(); // populate this with your data

var list = dict.Select(pair => new Customer { Id = pair.Key, Name = pair.Value }).ToList();
```

You can also use an appropriate `Customer` constructor (if available) instead of the example property setter syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
 List<Customer> list = theDictionary
                         .Select(e => new Customer { Id = e.Key, Name = e.Value })
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myList = (from d in myDictionary
             select new Customer {
               Key = d.Key,
               Name = d.Value
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `myDictionary` is populated and `myList` ist the target list:

```
myDictionary.ToList()
            .ForEach(x => 
                     myList.Add( new Customer() {Id = x.Key, Name = x.Value} )
                    );
```